# Kile not working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Error: Cannot open log file; did you run LaTeX?)

Tags: 14.04, latex, kile

I have recently updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to compile a .tex file using pdfLaTeX in Kile, I get the error message:

```
 Cannot open log file; did you run LaTeX?
```

I tried the following to install LaTeX based on what I saw here: http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-14-04lts/ :

```
 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

But get the error:

```
Processing was halted because there wE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help?!?

**update**:  Here is the output of `sudo apt-get install -f texlive-latex-extra` (note that there were many more `dpkg: error processing package...` messages that I could not include due to limitations on how long this post can be):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f texlive-latex-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-latex-extra is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alien debugedit libfontconfig1-dev libnxcl1 libpathplan4 librpmbuild3
  librpmsign1 libxcomp3 libxft-dev lsb-core lsb-security ncurses-term nxproxy
  pax plotutils rpm
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
81 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.ZI5jPMDD
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-sanskrit:
 latex-sanskrit depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-sanskrit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmodern:
 lmodern depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lmodern (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tex-gyre:
 tex-gyre depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                  dpkg: error processing package tex-gyre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super-minimal:
 cm-super-minimal depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super-minimal depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cm-super-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super:
 cm-super depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on cm-super-minimal (= 0.3.4-9); however:
  Package cm-super-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cm-super (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost:
 texlive-metapost depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context:
 context depends on texlive-metapost (>= 2013); however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.
 context depends on lmodern (>= 2.004.4); however:
  Package lmodern is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-gyre; however:
  Package tex-gyre is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context-modules:
 context-modules depends on context (>> 2011); however:
  Package context is not configured yet.
 context-modules depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of feynmf:
 feynmf depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package feynmf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kile:
 kile depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kile (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-common:
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1); however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese:
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese:
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-korean:
 latex-cjk-korean depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-korean depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-other:
 texlive-lang-other depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-other (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-thai:
 latex-cjk-thai depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-lang-other (>= 2013.20130523-1); however:
  Package texlive-lang-other is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-thai (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-all:
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-korean (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-korean is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-thai (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-thai is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latexmk:
 latexmk depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latexmk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of m-tx:
 m-tx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package m-tx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of musixtex:
 musixtex depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package musixtex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pmx:
 pmx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pmx depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pmx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of purifyeps:
 purifyeps depends on texlive-metapost; however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package purifyeps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-bibtex-extra:
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-bibtex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-formats-extra:
 texlive-formats-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-formats-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-formats-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-polish:
 texlive-lang-polish depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-polish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-polish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-extra:
 texlive-generic-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-indic:
 texlive-lang-indic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-indic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-spanish:
 texlive-lang-spanish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-spanish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-omega:
 texlive-omega depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-omega depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-omega (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-cyrillic:
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-cyrillic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-humanities-doc:
 texlive-humanities-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-humanities-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-english:
 texlive-lang-english depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-english (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fragmaster:
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fragmaster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra-doc:
 texlive-latex-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
.
.
.
.
.(MORE ERRORS HERE!!!! THIS IS MY EDIT TO MEET THE MAXIMUM CHARACTER LIMIT ALLOWED FOR A POST ON THIS FORUM!!!!!!!!!!!)
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package texlive-science-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 latex-sanskrit
 lmodern
 tex-gyre
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-recommended
 cm-super-minimal
 cm-super
 texlive-metapost
 context
 context-modules
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-extra-utils
 feynmf
 kile
 latex-xcolor
 latex-beamer
 latex-cjk-common
 latex-cjk-chinese
 latex-cjk-japanese
 latex-cjk-korean
 texlive-lang-other
 latex-cjk-thai
 latex-cjk-all
 latexmk
 m-tx
 musixtex
 pmx
 purifyeps
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive
 texlive-bibtex-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-formats-extra
 texlive-lang-polish
 texlive-generic-extra
 texlive-lang-indic
 texlive-lang-spanish
 texlive-omega
 texlive-lang-cyrillic
 texlive-humanities-doc
 texlive-lang-english
 fragmaster
 texlive-latex-extra-doc
 texlive-publishers-doc
 texlive-lang-european
 texlive-pictures-doc
 texlive-metapost-doc
 texlive-science-doc
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with one of the repositories registered with `apt`. Could you please post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: I added the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently found this problem. You can solve this by purging the tex-common package and then auto removing unnecessary packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge tex-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This way, you all your tex packages will be gone. Now, you can fresh install the TeX.